# AS3 transparent background

Tags: actionscript-3, background, transparency, flash-cs4, swfloader

I'm creating a game for an assignment and am using Flash CS4. I'm figuring the best way to do this is to create each room setting in a separate file and insert the characters (it's first person, so you only see his back the entire time). I don't want to just animate him for every room because it's basically the same actions he does in each one and at the beginning of the game you choose whether you're playing as a guy or girl... so instead of animating this twice I just want to import the animation as it plays.

I've learned how to import flash into an HTML file and make the background transparent, and I've also learned how to load a .swf using loader, URLRequest and addChild() in AC3. However, I can't do the latter and also keep the background transparent. Help!

Thanks!

Comment: If you see the characters back, then doesn't that make it 3rd person? not 1st person!

Comment: Also what's with the "AC3"? Do you mean "AS3"?

Answer (score 0):

it works by just importing the class as long as there's nothing on the background. turned out to be a simple question.